# How to make custom taxonomy pages per term based on fields?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a bunch of taxonomy terms, one for each county in a state.

I am going to use the taxonomy pages as landing pages in a Google Adwords campaign that is customized per county.

So, I have some boilerplate text that I want to use on all term pages, but I want to substitute the county name (which is the term name) and the biggest city in the county (which is input as a text field on the taxonomy term).

What's a quick way to do this in Drupal 8?  I tried to edit the **Taxonomy Term** view, but this is showing the content tagged by the term; in my case, there is no content tagged by the term. I want to use the term name and field data on the term to customize the boilerplate text.

Comment: IMO this is a perfect use case for Taxonomy Views Integrator. https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) and a custom block made in Views.

```
View of taxonomy terms, custom block
Contextual filter- taxonomy term: term ID
Provide default value: Term ID from URL

Pathauto pattern for taxonomy terms:
[term:tid]/mylinkpath/[term:name]

Go to taxonomy term display and add panelizer, then add custom views block.
```